# SQL Query to recursively calculate minimum over a column

Tags: sql, sqlite, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Consider the following table:

[image]

I'm trying to populate the columns "Window_30" and "Window Name" such that it gives me the rolling minimum dates across the last 30 days and then start another Window. Also the above windows are at Customer Id level. See below:

[image]

I tried recursive bigquery function but got an error saying "A subquery containing a recursive reference may not use an analytic function at []"

Comment: Why is this tagged SQLite?

Comment: Believe the same SQLite query can be used in bigquery. All I'm looking for is a pseudocode in sql really.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing lead and lag functions will work.

https://learnsql.com/blog/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql/

Comment: Lag window is dynamic based on 30 day condition. Not aware of any way to do this with lag function.

Answer (score 0):

Let the table be interactions(customer_id, interaction_date), then the following sqlite3 statement works:

```
/* tmp contains all months from min(interaction_date) up to max(interaction_date)
*/
with recursive tmp(m_start, m_end) as (
select strftime('%Y-%m-%d', min(interaction_date), 'start of month'),
       strftime('%Y-%m-%d', min(interaction_date),
                'start of month', '+40 days', 'start of month', '-1 days')
  from interactions
 union
select strftime('%Y-%m-%d', m_end, '+1 days'),
       strftime('%Y-%m-%d', m_end, '+40 days', 'start of month', '-1 days')
  from tmp
 where m_end <= (select max(interaction_date)
                 from interactions
                )
),
/* tmp2 contains one record for each customer having at least one
   interaction_date between m_start and m_end.
*/
tmp2(customer_id, m_start, m_end) as (
select distinct customer_id,
       m_start, m_end
  from interactions
       join tmp on interaction_date between m_start and m_end
),
/* tmp3: with the window function row_number we enumerate the records for each
   customer.
*/
tmp3 as (
select customer_id, m_start, m_end,
       row_number() over (partition by customer_id) as wk
from tmp2
)
select i.customer_id, interaction_date as window_30, 'W' || wk as window_name
 from interactions i
      join tmp3 t on t.customer_id = i.customer_id
                   and interaction_date between m_start and m_end
 order by i.customer_id, interaction_date;
```